# I am trying to make some interesting changes to the editing area of vscode. I want to know whether the API supports the following two features?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

First, does the vscode editor area support the insertion of some lines, only for display purposes, and does not affect the properties of the editing area itself, such as the line number unchanged. I know that Gitlens can display the relevant information of the author after a certain line, now I want to insert these non-editable information into separate lines.

Second, in the editor area where the breakpoint is marked during debugging (that is, to the left of the line number), can a new column be added to show some messages corresponding to the line? Or can I just modify the line number, add some characters to the left of it?

I have been searching for several days, and I have not found such an interface to call.

Thanks.

Comment: This extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomasz-smykowski.assistant was able to show the codelens lines above the current line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried the plugin you mentioned, which uses the class CodeLens provided by vscode.It used to insert an infomation, whitch represents a command that should be shown along with source text, like the number of references, a way to run tests, above the specified source text.When inserting in a blank line, the indentation of the inserted information takes no effect. And it doesn't support to insert multiple lines continuously. I need it deeply. 
Earlier I tried Decorator, it can insert text before or after the same line of modified text, but not below the line.

Answer (score 1):

The first feature you can have by implementing the CodeLens provider in your codebase. Here is a sample:

```
export class MyCodeLensProvider implements CodeLensProvider {
    async provideCodeLenses(document: TextDocument): Promise<CodeLens[]> {
        let location = new Range(0, 0, 0, 0)

        let codeLens = new CodeLens(location, {
            command: 'say.testCmd',
            title: 'Insert console here',
        })

        return [codeLens];
    }
}
```

Regarding the second feature, you can have icons before the line number by setting gutterIcon, here is a little snippet that I have extracted from my codebase, hope this will give you hint; how to achieve what you were looking:

```
const todoStyle = {
    text: "TODO:",
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#ffbd2a',
    overviewRulerColor: 'rgba(255,0,42,0.8)',
    dark: {
        gutterIconPath: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'src', 'resources', 'dark', 'todo.png')
    }
}
const fontColorDecorator = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType(style.todoStyle);

    /* Ranges */
    let ranges: vscode.Range[] = [];
    const startPos = new vscode.Position(lineNumber, characterPosition);
    const endPos = new vscode.Position(lineNumber, characterPosition); 
    let singleRange: vscode.Range = new vscode.Range(startPos, endPos);
    ranges.push(singleRange);

    activeEditor.setDecorations(fontColorDecorator, ranges);
```

**Note:** Make sure to adjust the path and set proper ranges. For simplicity, I am only pushing one position in the range array. If you want to have effects on multiple lines then add more ranges accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the first method you mentioned, and it doesn't quite meet the needs. The second idea looks so great. How can I get the range of the line number location? The ranges array in your code.

Comment: @anOrange: I have updated my code snippet to show how to populate the ranges as well. Please accept/up vote if the answer is helpful.

Comment: I modified the code, and I don't quite understand the position of range. If I write it like this, I will add some characters in front of the editing area on line 10 instead of the line number.

Comment: ` let activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    const decoration = {
        before: {
            contentText: 'line test', 
            color: 'red',
        }
    }
    const fontColorDecorator = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType(decoration);
    const range = { range: new vscode.Range(10, 0, 10, 0) }; // the line number is 10
    let ranges = [];
    ranges.push(range);
    activeEditor.setDecorations(fontColorDecorator, ranges);`

Comment: Your decoration code will append the sentence 'line test' in red color and it will appear in the text area on the specified line. At first glance, it may look like a part of the document that users can change/interact, but users cant change the text actually.

Comment: Actually I can insert an icon on the left side of line number follow your code, but still cannot insert a text. Thanks anyway. I've voted for you already.

Comment: @anOrange: You can put small text like a number on the place of the icon. For that, you have to use an SVG and then put your text content inside SVG. For reference you can check this : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.numbered-bookmarks. 
There is an up & down triangle before the question and answer, if you find the answers helpful please consider clicking the up arrow to vote the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I‘ve voted. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.