# Is there a VSCode API to insert some uneditable lines in the editor for displaying information?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there an API to insert multiple lines in an editor, similar to [ThemableDecorationAttachmentRenderOptions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ThemableDecorationAttachmentRenderOptions), but not limited to a single line. I would like to insert multiple lines of text which are not editable, and do not affect the editor line numbers like  [CodeLens](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeLens).

In context with the first part of the question,
[I am trying to make some interesting changes to the editing area of vscode. I want to know whether the API supports the following two features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446749/i-am-trying-to-make-some-interesting-changes-to-the-editing-area-of-vscode-i-wa),
where a similar functionality is asked about but not answered.

Comment: add multiple Codelens lines all bound to an empty command

Comment: @rioV8 The problem with adding multiple CodeLenses on a range is that the CodeLenses will always show in the same line, and can even have CodeLens from other extensions provided in that line.
I want something like multiple CodeLenses, without command, on a function but spanning multiple lines.

Comment: you can have a look at the `comment-sample` sample program

Comment: @rioV8 Unfortunately, [Comments](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Comment) don't seem to be what I'm looking for. I came across [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85682) with proposed changes for an editor inset, but I need an option to insert multiline text rather than a [Webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Webview).

Comment: just adding a few `p` tags to a Webview is not more work than constructing your text only inset.